# How to achieve that my changes in current branch will not spread among all branches?

Tags: git, branch

I am still bit confused with the git, although I used to work with some version control systems before. My question is about branches. My understanding is that when I would like to try to develop some feature and I am not sure about the result, I'll do that in branch. To achieve this I would create branch "srbac" (as I did) from master. Then I checked out the srbac, so it was my working copy. I have made couple of changes.

Now my colleague sent me a pull request, so I created branch called "john" and pull his changes to this branch. I made that branch working copy and tried to pull it to my local repository. But this did not work, because, as the SourceTree application (I am using that one for git) said, there were some uncommitted changes on my local repository. But these were from "srbac" branch! These should not be in "john" branch, neither in "master" (those were there too).

Now the message (git status) said that I could "stash" those changes. So I did. In "john" branch checked out. They're now gone from every branch.

What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when changing branches, uncommitted changes move along with you. if this is not what you want, you must commit them somewhere. the stash is this special place/branch where you can commit to from every branch (but that is separate from every real branch). so if you stash your changes, they are no longer in the current branch and will not appear when changing branches. they are exclusively in the stash. to get them back, move to the branch where you want to have them and do `git stash pop` and the changes will appear in your working directory (not as a commit, but as changed files) and the entry in the stash will be removed.

n.b. `stash apply` gets the changes and does not delete the stash entry.